# Unix Server migration

Tags: unix

i work with unix server 11.31. Now i want to move my binaries to unix 11.11. I am confused will those binaries will work in 11.11 since there was some signal changes and configuration changes in newer version.

Comment: I assume you talk about HP-UX? And why do you want to migrate to an 12 year old OS (11.11) from a five year old (11.31)?

Comment: Since my production server is in earlier version i need to move my binaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary compatibility is only *usually* guaranteed on forward versions (i.e. binaries compiled on version xx.1 will run on xx.2).  I do not specifically know how HP handles this for HP-UX, but I would expect it **not** to guarantee backward binary compatibility.

You would be safer off re-compiling your code against the previous version.

Or, you could move the binaries and see if they run - might be quickest.

More info on some HP-UX binary compatibility stuff [here](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801?ciid=8808f321e5f02110f321e5f02110275d6e10RCRD).

Comment: But my binaries working in 11.11 were not working in 11.31...i need to do certain changes. Hence am confused due to these changes will it work in 11.11